# Cant insert >1000 records in VS 2012 SqlExpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

Uhmm well .. i have a local DB .. created using VS 2012 .. not the LocalDB .. its SqlExpress x64 ..

i have a C# program that reads and parses a txt file .. and converts the data into records .. and around 200,000 records are inserted in one flow of execution .. the program parses and creates a insert query and executes it ..

i have used Sql objects .. SqlCommand .. SqlConnection ..... for insertion ..

the problem is that the console C# application does show that all records are inserted successfully till last count ..

but i can see only 1000 records in DB Table ..

Code to insert:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace SentiWordDBPopulate
{
class DBPopulateSentiWord
{
    static SqlCommand sqlCmd;
    static SqlConnection sqlConn;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost\\SqlExpress; DataBase=WordDBForBlogMiner; integrated security=true");
            sqlConn.Open();
            //sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select * from KWTable", sqlConn);

            //skip 1st 13 lines
            //for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
            //fin.ReadLine();

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Ritesh\\Desktop\\WordDB.txt");

            Console.WriteLine("Done reading! Press enter to insert everything into DB.");
            Console.Read();

            long IDCounter = 0;
            //enter next 117658 lines into DB
            for (int i = 13; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                //string line =fin.ReadLine();
                string[] s = (lines[i].Remove(lines[i].IndexOf('#')).Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                //s[5] = s[6] = null;
                s[2] = s[2].Equals("NaN") ? "0" : s[2];
                s[3] = s[3].Equals("NaN") ? "0" : s[3];
                float tempNegScore = float.Parse(s[3]), tempPosScore = float.Parse(s[2]);
                int negScore = (int)Math.Round((tempNegScore * 27), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                int posScore = (int)Math.Round((tempPosScore * 31), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

                if (posScore <= 31 && negScore <= 27)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine((++IDCounter) + "\t => " + s[0] + "\t" + posScore + "\t" + negScore + "\t" + s[4]);
                    string category = "";
                    if (posScore.Equals(0) && negScore.Equals(0))
                        category = "neutral";
                    else if (posScore > 0 && negScore.Equals(0))
                        category = "positive";
                    else if (posScore.Equals(0) && negScore > 0)
                        category = "negative";
                    else if (posScore > 0 && negScore > 0)
                        category = "PosNeg";

                    string query = "insert into SentiWordKWTable values ('" + s[0] + "', " + (++IDCounter) + ", " + posScore + ", " + negScore + ", '" + s[4].Replace("'", "") + "', '" + category + "')";
                    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("Record Num: " + IDCounter + " successfully inserted!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((++IDCounter) + "\t => " + s[0] + "\t" + posScore + "\t" + negScore + "\t" + s[4]);
                    break;
                }

                tempNegScore = tempPosScore = 0;
                posScore = negScore = 0;
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occured => " + e.Message);
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("delete from SentiWordKWTable", sqlConn);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("all rows of table deleted");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

it was not a problem earlier in VS 2008 .. is there some restriction in VS 2012 .. or something to enable for >1000 insertion? ..

Comment: can you share the code of method that you are using to insert the records in a loop.. ? perhaps there is a simple oversight and a second pair of eyes or more can help you to correct this issue..

Comment: Have you tried doing "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR TABLE"?

Comment: @rontornambe when i click on the table . the table does show the proper approx row cnt in properties ..

Comment: Have you tried doing sqlCmd.Commit; or do a Select Count(*) from your table to get record count..

Comment: hmm ok .. wait for few mins ..i'll check the output for those ..

Comment: also if you want to skip first 13 lines shouldn't your loop be for for (int i = 12; i < lines.Length; i++)

Comment: It should also be notes that concatenation is the worst possible way to build SQL queries: parameters should **always** be preferred

Comment: count query does give proper count ..

Comment: The usual "gotcha" with SQL express is people using a user-instance (file etc) looking in the **wrong file** (project copy of the database vs build output copy), and then overwriting the file every time they press play. Is it as simple as that?

Comment: I'm now assuming that .. we can have only 1000 records "visible" .. i think all records are inserted but only 1000 are visible at a time .. is that so?

Comment: none of the files are overwritten .. neither txt nor sqlExpress .. i have executed only once

Comment: i tried googling .. and somewhere it had mentioned that SqlBulkCopy was to be used for >1000 records .. does anyone know that?

Comment: and if its the visibility .. i cant browse other next 1000 records too ..

Comment: Are you looking this trough SQL server managment studio ?

Comment: i was looking via Server Explorer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the visibility option only. There is a small toolbar at top which has a field: Max Rows: 1000
I selected "All" in that and everything is visible ... * facepalm *

Sorry for trouble everybody, and thanks @MarcGravell I'll use parameters instead of concatenation.

Comment: I would be lying if I said I've never made this mistake.